Button Click Event not getting triggered on iOS devices
<div class="ms-auto">
                            <div>
                                <button type="button" title="1 Month" class="btn btn-soft-secondary btn-sm ms-1" [ngClass]="{ 'active': activeFilter === '1m' }" (click)="applyFilters('1m')">
                                    1M
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" title="3 Months" class="btn btn-soft-secondary btn-sm ms-1" [ngClass]="{ 'active': activeFilter === '3m' }" (click)="applyFilters('3m')">
                                    3M
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" title="6 Months" class="btn btn-soft-secondary btn-sm ms-1" [ngClass]="{ 'active': activeFilter === '6m' }" (click)="applyFilters('6m')">
                                    6M
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" title="1 Year" class="btn btn-soft-secondary btn-sm ms-1" [ngClass]="{ 'active': activeFilter === '1y' }" (click)="applyFilters('1y')">
                                    1Y
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" title="2020 onward till date" class="btn btn-soft-secondary btn-sm ms-1" [ngClass]="{ 'active': activeFilter === 'all' }" (click)="applyFilters('all')">
                                    All
                                </button>
                            </div>
</div>

(click) event is working everywhere normally but it does not get triggered on iPhone (Safari + Chrome)

Not an angular expert but I guess you need to do a (touch) or (tab) handler?

@Xiduzo I tried touchdown but that did not help. Same behaviour.
